# Matrix decomposition: is it right?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I'm trying to develop a method for representing my symmetric matrix A as a composition of two matrices such as: A = t(B)*B.

We know that

​t(P)*А*​Р​ = ​D

where

P - matrix of eigenvectors

D - diagonal matrix of eigenvalues λi

Therefore

t(S)*​D*S = E

where

S - diagonal matrix of 1/sqrt(λi)

t(S)*​t(P)*A*P*S = E

t(P*S)*A*(PS) = E

Given P*S = inv(B):

t(inv(B))*А*inv​(B) = E

inv(t(B))*А*inv​(B) = E

А*inv​(B) = t(B)

A = ​t(B)*B

That's what we wanted. Thus, to obtain a matrix B we need to find eigenvectors and eigenvalues, construct matrix S, multiply it by P and then find an inverse matrix.

However, I tried to do this and found out that ​t(B)*B != A at all. Where did it go wrong?

Comment: Use MathJax, this is too hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Using your notation, the whole idea is

$$P^TAP=D=S^{-1}S^{-1}$$

then

$$A=\left(PS^{-1}\right) (S^{-1}P^T)=(S^{-1}P^T)^T(S^{-1}P^T)$$

and hence $B=S^{-1}P^T$ which is more commonly written as $B=D^{\frac12}P^T$.

Your derivation is correct. Without showing your computation, it's hard to know what went wrong.

A common mistake that I see is forgetting to  make the  $P$ an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: I see. I use R for computations.
While computing solve(inv(B)) R gives an error "system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.06664e-17". So I googled and added parameter "tol = 1e-17". 
Is it possible that the problem is connected with this step?

Comment: Did you use %*% for matrix multiplication? if you just want cholesky factorization, just use chol. Also, I don't think there is a need to compute inverse.

Comment: Yes, I did. And I computed a matrix P with prcomp. 
As far as I know, Cholesky factorization produces a triangular matrix B and I don't want that.

Comment: You just need to compute $D^{\frac12}P^T$. No inverse is needed, you might want to check if $P^TP=I$.

Comment: Would you, please, explain what you mean by D^(0.5)? A matrix with a diagonal elements equal to sqrt of the elements of a matrix D?

Comment: I mean $\operatorname{diag}(\sqrt{\lambda_1}, \ldots, \sqrt{\lambda_n})$